# Cannot get tracks in a playlist on Android 10

Tags: android, audio, media, playlist

I am trying to get a list of the playlists and how many tacks are in each on a device with Android 10 installed.  I am using compileSdkVersion = targetSdkVersion = 30. I am requesting READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, which seems to be necessary.

I have never tried this before, but it seems straightforward: Get a cursor of the playlists and using the _id of that playlist, then get a cursor over the tracks.

It works as expected as far as getting the name and data (the location), but it always returns 1 for the _id, and it finds no tracks (i.e. cursor.getCount() is zero). The files are not empty. I may have a stupid error, but I am not seeing it.

Added 7/22/2021: There are only 5 column names returned with *: date_modified, _id, name, _data, date_added. The values for all except _id are correct (or at least reasonable). _id (MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID) is always 1.

This is the code:

> ```
> private void showPlaylists() {
>     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>     sb.append("\nPlaylists\n");
>     Uri collection;
>     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
>         collection = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
>     } else {
>         collection = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
>     }
>     String name, data;
>     long id;
>     // External
>     try (Cursor playListCursor =
>                  this.getContentResolver().query(
>                          collection,
>                          null, null, null, null)) {
>         if (playListCursor == null) {
>             sb.append("Cannot access external playlists\n");
>             return;
>         }
>         for (int i = 0; i < playListCursor.getCount(); i++) {
>             playListCursor.moveToPosition(i);
>             name = playListCursor.getString(
>                     playListCursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
>             sb.append(i).append(" ").append(name).append("\n");
>             // This is apparently the path
>             data = playListCursor.getString(
>                     playListCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
>             sb.append("    ").append(data).append("\n");
>             id = playListCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID);
>             sb.append("    id=").append(id).append("\n");
>
>             // Get the playlist from the id
>             String[] projection = null; // All columns
>             try (Cursor cursor =
>                          this.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore
>                                          .Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri
>                                                  ("external", id),
>                                  projection, null, null, null)) {
>                 if (cursor == null) {
>                     sb.append("    Cannot get contents\n");
>                 } else {
>                     sb.append("    Tracks: ").append(cursor.getCount())
>                             .append("\n");
>                 }
>             } catch (Exception ex) {
>                 String msg = "    Error getting playlist " + i;
>                 Log.e(TAG, msg, ex);
>             }
>         }
>     } catch (Exception ex) {
>         String msg = "Error getting external playlists";
>         Utils.excMsg(this, msg, ex);
>         Log.e(TAG, msg, ex);
>     }
>     Log.e(TAG, sb.toString());
> }
> ```

and this is the output in Logcat:

> ```
> 0 Carmen Cavallero
>     /storage/3535-6434/Playlists/Carmen Cavallero.m3u
>     id=1
>     Tracks: 0
> 1 Chris Botti
>     /storage/3535-6434/Playlists/Chris Botti.m3u
>     id=1
>     Tracks: 0
> 2 Diana Krall
>     /storage/3535-6434/Playlists/Diana Krall.m3u
>     id=1
>     Tracks: 0
> 3 Dinner Party
>     /storage/3535-6434/Playlists/Dinner Party.m3u
>     id=1
>     Tracks: 0
> 4 Meditation 1
>     /storage/3535-6434/Playlists/Meditation 1.m3u
>     id=1
>     Tracks: 0
> 5 Romance
>     /storage/3535-6434/Playlists/Romance.m3u
>     id=1
>     Tracks: 0
> 6 Tablet
>     /storage/3535-6434/Playlists/Tablet.m3u
>     id=1
>     Tracks: 0
> 7 Jean Sidwell
>     /storage/3535-6434/Playlists/Jean Sidwell.m3u
>     id=1
>     Tracks: 0
> 8 Bill Evans MM2
>     /storage/3535-6434/Playlists/Bill Evans MM2.m3u
>     id=1
>     Tracks: 0
> 9 Selena
>     /storage/3535-6434/Playlists/Selena.m3u
>     id=1
>     Tracks: 0
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to apply the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission for android 10.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

For more details,check [Docs](https://developer.android.google.cn/training/data-storage/manage-all-files?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks, but that did not help. My interpretation of the docs is that it shouldn't be needed if I am not changing anything.

Comment: Kenneth, are you able to create actual playlists with tracks on the xternal storage that are stored in the android 11 media database? If so would you mind getting in touch? theo.klink@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach

```
   public Uri get_audio_playlist_members_uri(Long playlist_id){
if(playlist_id==null){
    playlist_id= 0L;
}
    Uri uri_to_use = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

        uri_to_use   = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
                .buildUpon()
                .appendEncodedPath(Long.toString(playlist_id))
                .appendEncodedPath("members")
                .build();
    } else {
        uri_to_use = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                .buildUpon()
                .appendEncodedPath(Long.toString(playlist_id))
                .appendEncodedPath("members")
                .build();
    }
    return uri_to_use;
}

public Cursor getPlaylistTracks(Context context, Long playlist_id) {
    if (context != null) {
        Uri newuri = uris.get_audio_playlist_members_uri(playlist_id);
        ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        String _id = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members._ID;
        String audio_id = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID;
        String artist = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.ARTIST;
        String album = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.ALBUM;
        String album_id = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.ALBUM_ID;
        String title = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.TITLE;
        String duration = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.DURATION;
        String location = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.DATA;
        String composer = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.COMPOSER;
        String playorder = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER;
        String date_modified = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.DATE_MODIFIED;
        String[] columns = {_id, audio_id, artist, album_id, album, title, duration,
                location, date_modified, playorder, composer};
        try {
            return resolver.query(newuri, columns, null, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try using your code as copied from above.  It didn't fix the problem, which was related to the fact that the id was always 1.  I later discovered I was using the column index of the id, not the id.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I was using:

> ```
>             id = playListCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID));
> ```

rather than:

> ```
>             id = playListCursor.getLong(playListCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID));
> ```

My mistake. Sorry.

Comment: yes, if id is long then of course. My code works though

Comment: Kenneth, did you see my question on whether you are able to create android (10 and higher) playlists for tracks located on the external memory. If so can you contact me please. theo.klink@gmail.com